# Python check if keys inside keys exist in dictionary and continue otherwise

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a dictionary with multiple keys which have other keys inside, as well as lists. Example:

```
dictABC=
{
    "name": "bob",
    "id": "abs",
    "meta": {
        "v": "2",
        "update": "00"
    },
    "other": {
        "age": [
            {
                "a": "test",
                "b": "test1",
                "c": "test2"
            },
            {
                "a": "user",
                "b": "user1",
                "c": "user2"
            }
        ]
      }
    }
```

I want a routine to check if some keys exist, if yes, get value, if not continue checking the next one, until all the list of keys has been checked. At the end I will create a dictionary with those key-values that exist in `dictABC`

How can I do this? How can I check if key `dictABC["other"]["age"][0]["a"]` exist form inside the list?

Currently I have

```
list_keys = ["name", "update", "a"]
keys = []
values = []
for k in list_keys:
    if k in dictABC:
        keys.append(k)
        values.append(dictABC[k])
newDict = {k:v for k,v in zip(keys, values)}
print(new)
```

Comment: What you want is not fully clear. Do you want to get a flat list of keys? Ensure that keys exists to be able to run `dictABC["other"]["age"][0]["a"]`? What is your goal in terms of application? What is the expected output?

Comment: There is: https://pypi.org/project/jsonpath-ng/

Comment: @mozway thanks for the reply, I want to have a loop that checks some keys (for example that "a" key which is inside a list and key) and creates a new Dictionary with key-values that exist. I tried try/except too but it stops after one of the keys does not exist. And I want all the keys in a list to be checked

Comment: What if the same key occurs multiple times, at different levels or in different branches of the data tree?

Comment: @Arne good question, I just want the key for a specific level; do I need to implement IF statements for each key, or is there a way of looping?